# Extract a substring from the filename in Unix

Tags: unix, filenames

I have a file name with the following pattern -

```
Fisrt_Part_20140710.dat_07-10-2014_23:15:36.gz
```

I want to remove both the dates, timestamp and the extension gz from the file name, so the output file name will look like this -

```
First_part.dat
```

Also, I don't want to change the name of the actual file, but I need to generate a list of such files for a report in a txt file so I am not worried about the extension gz much.

I tried using sed command and tried a lot of options with it but can't get it to work for me.

Since I am not very familiar with Unix and sed much, any pointers would be of great help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a (naive) way to do it:

The following command:
`echo First_Part_20140710.dat_07-10-2014_23:15:36.gz | sed -e 's/_[0-9]*\.dat.*/.dat/g'`

Outputs:
`First_Part.dat`

Limitations:
First_Part must not contain any numbers, or the string '.dat'